# How to detect css value source?

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I need to detect the css value source for a component, currently, I get this in `react-native-debugger`:

[image]

I can't find the style source that caused the padding value to be 14 as above.

Any idea how to debug this?
I am from a web design background, I usually use Chrome to find the source css file, but in react-native I am just starting to learn.

Comment: You want to know what file have a style that is causing the padding?

Comment: just look at the component's styles. *<Component style={[...]} />*

Comment: Yes i want to know from where this padding is coming ... i commented my Entire style component and the padding still exists